# Laravel recaptcha validation in registrar does not work

Tags: laravel-5, recaptcha

I am newbie in Laravel.
I've used this recaptcha package: https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha
And the documentation saids that: 
In your validation rules, add the following:

```
$rules = array(
        // ...
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
    };
```

By the way I use the laravel 5's Registrar:

```
<?php namespace taxman\Services;

use taxman\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar as RegistrarContract;

class Registrar implements RegistrarContract {

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
            'telephone' => 'required',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    public function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

}
```

But in this case the laravel return with a error message: "The g-recaptcha-response is required", however in the view I used this command:

```
<div class="form-group">
         {!! Recaptcha::render() !!}
 </div>
```

And yes, the field is not empty!

So, I think, I should put the `'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'` somewhere else?
Because it seems, in the Registrar's validator does not work.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem? I have probably the same one.

Answer (score 11):

if someone is still pulling their hair because of this issue just remove the `'recaptcha'` in validation rule.

use

```
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required'
```

instead of

```
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'
```

see http://tuts.codingo.me/google-recaptcha-in-laravel-application/

Comment: It fixed but I'm still asking why. Removing problem is not really solution. BTW the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

if you paste the following in the controller where this action happends it should work.

$this->validate($request,['g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha']);

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify, you need to check **g-recaptcha-response** POST parameter. So pass it to the validator() function.